# Language on Botframework

Tags: c#, locale, botframework

Im goind through the bot framwork and Im having trouble fixing the global language.
The problem is that I cannot change the backend commands and responses that are built in the framework, they are always in english.

For example, in Formflow, I would like to enter "help" but in other language instead. 
Or whenever a question in a QnAbot is not found, I would like the defaul "...Is not a valid query" to be in another lenguage instead

Are different languages built in or do I need to code every commmand translation?

Answer (score 0):

If you’d like to implement localization, you can try to create resource files for language that you want and add&use it in your project. When a form is created, the `IFormBuilder.Build` method will automatically look for resources that contain your form type name and use them to localize the static strings in your form.

This article describes [Localize form content](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/bot-framework/dotnet/bot-builder-dotnet-formflow-localize), please refer to it. And you can find these main steps:

> Generate a resource file, you can either use IFormBuilder.SaveResources or use the RView tool
>
> After generated a resource file, add it to project and then set the neutral language withe these steps:
>
> 1. Right-click on your project and select Application.
> 2. Click Assembly Information.
> 3. Select the Neutral Language value that corresponds to the language in which you developed your bot.
>
> After added resource files to project, use the [Multilingual App Toolkit (MAT)](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/develop/multilingual-app-toolkit) to localize them.

Comment: Hi, thx. Ive done that but that is only for the strings on the form. I need to change the build in strings. Like Help. Reset, Yes, No. They are always in english. I need them in Swedish instead.

Comment: As I know, these FormCommand entries are localized: [translated resource files](https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder/tree/682ed1766713940c8bb382508b5ae68c216c7113/CSharp/Library/Microsoft.Bot.Builder/Resource), but not translated in Swedish, you can [open an issue](https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder/issues) to give a feedback. Besides, as a workaround, you can try to detect and translate user input commands (as you mentioned) by yourself in your bot application code.

Comment: Thx. Those files contain Exactly The responses I need.  I should be able to translate that resource file to Swedish manually.

Comment: Yes, you can try to manually translate that resource file to Swedish.

Comment: I have translated it but I not really sure on how to include them in my project so that the bot.builder uses it.

Answer (score 0):

you can try it by using

```
var english = new Option();
english.Locale = "en-US";
```

Reference: [GitHub](https://github.com/EricDahlvang/ChooseLanguageBot/blob/master/ChooseLanguageBot/Dialogs/LanguageChoiceDialog.cs)